# How to stop an application on only one server in a cluster?

Tags: java, weblogic, jmx, weblogic11g, mbeans

#### How can I stop an application deployed to a cluster on only specific servers?

I want to use the `AppDeploymentRuntimesMBean` to issue an application `stop` command to a deployed application, but to only specific servers in the cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do exactly what you're asking:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/apirefs.1111/e13951/mbeans/AppDeploymentRuntimeMBean.html?skipReload=true#stop

When you call stop you can tell it what 'targets' to stop the application on. A target can be a single managed server or a cluster.

There is a fully coded example in their documentation here:

http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/DEPRF/api_intro.htm#BHCHFGGD

Comment: searched for 2 days and never came across this example!